# Spring websocket: how convert easily the Message<?>'s payload to POJO in ChannelInterceptorAdapter

Tags: spring, spring-websocket

I have a Spring App working with websocket

I can do the connection and send messages etc.

The `@Controller` is:

```
    @MessageMapping("/ws/notification")
    @SendTo("/topic/springframework.topic.websocket.reply")
    public NotificationReply handleNotification(Notification notification) {
     ...
    }
```

It works fine. Observe the parameter type, `Notification`, it is a custom object.

Now because audit purposes I have the following:

```
@Component
public class MessageChannelInterceptorAdapter extends ChannelInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public void postSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel, boolean sent) {

        StompHeaderAccessor stompHeaderAccessor = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(message);

           ....

        switch(stompHeaderAccessor.getCommand()) {
            case CONNECT:
                logger.info("postSend ...");
                logger.info("STOMP Connect");
                break;
            ...
            case SEND:
                logger.info("postSend ...");
                logger.info("STOMP Send");
                printDetails(message, stompHeaderAccessor);
                break;

        ...
    } 


    private void printDetails(Message<?> message, StompHeaderAccessor stompHeaderAccessor) {
        logger.info("   {}", message.toString());
        logger.info("       Payload: {}", message.getPayload());
        logger.info("       Payload (String): {}", message.getPayload().toString());
        logger.info("           Payload (Class): {}", message.getPayload().getClass());

        if(stompHeaderAccessor.getDestination()!=null && stompHeaderAccessor.getDestination().equals("/app/ws/notification")) {
            logger.info("Aprrrr");
            Notification notification = (Notification) message.getPayload();
            logger.info("{}", notification);
        }
```

I get:

```
ERROR o.s.w.s.m.StompSubProtocolHandler - 
Failed to send client message to application via MessageChannel in session 555qe12a. 
Sending STOMP ERROR to client. 
org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: 
Failed to send message to ExecutorSubscribableChannel[clientInboundChannel]; 
nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: 
[B cannot be cast to com.manuel.jordan.websocket.message.Notification
```

I understand that `[B` is a `byte[]`.

Thus exists an easy way with the current `Spring Framework` API to do a cast for the `Message<?>` payload to a specific POJO?.

Remember to be applied within the class that it is extending from `ChannelInterceptorAdapter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AbstractMessageBrokerConfiguration` provides this bean:

```
@Bean
public CompositeMessageConverter brokerMessageConverter() {
```

You need to inject this bean into your `MessageChannelInterceptorAdapter` and call its `fromMessage(Message<?> message, Class<?> targetClass)`:

```
Notification notification = (Notification) this.messageConverter.fromMessage(message, Notification.class);
```

Comment: Thanks. BTW: some clue about to avoid `stompHeaderAccessor.getDestination().equals("/app/ws/notification")` in the `if` statement? I mean, I must do use that to use the `fromMessage` working with the `Notification` type explicitly.

Comment: No, that's not. The `@MessageMapping` routing logic is done later after the `MessageChannel`. You can consider to use an AOP Advice on your `@MessageMapping` methods instead. And this way you really would have the full access to the target arguments and so on.

Comment: Interesting. I thought and tried prior to create this post the following `if(payload.getClass().equals(Notification.class.getClass()))` and it does not work. That's why I use `stompHeaderAccessor.getDestination().equals("/app/ws/notification")` in the `if` statement. Your suggestion has sense of course