# Spring Websocket: how intercept the return type from the @MessageMapping reply

Tags: spring, spring-websocket

I have a Spring App working with websocket

I can do the connection and send messages etc.

The `@Controller` is:

```
@MessageMapping("/ws/notification")
@SendTo("/topic/springframework.topic.websocket.reply")
public NotificationReply handleNotification(Notification notification) {
 ...
}
```

Observe the `Notification` and `NotificationReply` types.

Until here all work how is expected

I have a class extending `ChannelInterceptorAdapter` and using the method:

- `public void postSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel, boolean sent)`

I am able to retrieve in someway the `Notification` type.

More details in:

- [Spring websocket: how convert easily the Message's payload to POJO in ChannelInterceptorAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50419131/spring-websocket-how-convert-easily-the-messages-payload-to-pojo-in-channel)

But now considering the *return* type.

- Where and How I can intercept in the same way the `NotificationReply` type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After to did do a research I did realize that the `StompCommand` enum has the following content:

```
public enum StompCommand {

    // client
    STOMP(SimpMessageType.CONNECT),
    CONNECT(SimpMessageType.CONNECT),
    DISCONNECT(SimpMessageType.DISCONNECT),
    SUBSCRIBE(SimpMessageType.SUBSCRIBE, true, true, false),
    UNSUBSCRIBE(SimpMessageType.UNSUBSCRIBE, false, true, false),
    SEND(SimpMessageType.MESSAGE, true, false, true),
    ACK(SimpMessageType.OTHER),
    NACK(SimpMessageType.OTHER),
    BEGIN(SimpMessageType.OTHER),
    COMMIT(SimpMessageType.OTHER),
    ABORT(SimpMessageType.OTHER),

    // server
    CONNECTED(SimpMessageType.OTHER),
    RECEIPT(SimpMessageType.OTHER),
    MESSAGE(SimpMessageType.MESSAGE, true, true, true),
    ERROR(SimpMessageType.OTHER, false, false, true);

    ...
```

Thus observe that `MESSAGE` is under 'server'. Therefore the solution is add a `case` for `MESSAGE` as follows:

```
    @Override
    public void postSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel, boolean sent) {

        StompHeaderAccessor stompHeaderAccessor = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(message);

           ....

        switch(stompHeaderAccessor.getCommand()) {
            case CONNECT:
                logger.info("postSend ...");
                logger.info("STOMP Connect");
                break;
            ...
            case MESSAGE:
                logger.info("postSend ...");
                logger.info("STOMP MESSAGE");
                .... do more
                break;
            ...
            case SEND:
                logger.info("postSend ...");
                logger.info("STOMP Send");
                printDetails(message, stompHeaderAccessor);
                break;

        ...
    }
```

If you want check the `payload` of the `Message<?>` you can do the following:

- [Spring websocket: how convert easily the Message's payload to POJO in ChannelInterceptorAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50419131/spring-websocket-how-convert-easily-the-messages-payload-to-pojo-in-channel)